# How to Connect to Testnet

Tags: testnet

I'm following the [tutorial for deploying a contract on the Testnet](https://assets.tqtezos.com/docs/setup/1-tezos-client/) on an Ubuntu 18.04 VirtualBox VM running on a Windows 10 host.  Per the tutorial instructions, I ran the following commands:

```
wget https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/releases/latest/download/tezos-client
chmod +x tezos-client
alias tezos-client=$PWD/tezos-client
```

However, when I execute

```
tezos-client -A rpcalpha.tzbeta.net -P 443 -S config update
```

I get

> Warning:
>     Failed to acquire the protocol version from the node
>     Rpc request failed:
>        - meth: GET
>        - uri: https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net:443/chains/main/blocks/head/protocols
>        - error: Unable to connect to the node: "No SSL or TLS support compiled into Conduit"

The instructions are rather straight forward, so I'm lost as to why I cannot connect to the Testnet. What do I need to do to connect to the Testnet?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in the tezos-packaging repository. We have fixed it in the v7.1-2 release. Can you please try again with v7.1-2 or newer? You can run `wget https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/releases/latest/download/tezos-client` to overwrite the version you have, it should work because it downloads the latest release (where the bug is fixed).